# Referring to a model outside of "this" context

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to set a listenTo on an event not in the current context of "this" in my view.

In my "Comment" View I have:

```
var app = app || {};

app.CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'div',

  template: _.template( $('#comment-template').html() ),

  // "<event> <selector>" : "<method>" aka function defined below
  events: {
    'click .up' : 'addUpVote',
    'click .down' :'subtractUpVote',
    'click .destroy_comment' : 'removeOneComment',
    'click .destroy-vote' : 'destroyVote'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    this.listenTo(app.Vote, 'add', this.render); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    this.$el.find('#vote-buttons').html();//(PASS IN VOTE TEMPLATE//);
    this.$el.attr('comment_id', this.model.get('id'));

    return this;
  },

removeOneComment: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
  },

voteAttributes: function() {
  return {
    comment_id: this.model.get('id'),
    };
  },

addUpVote: function( event ) {
  var vote = new app.Vote(this.voteUpAttributes());
  vote.save({
    success: function (vote) {
      vote.toJSON();
    }
  });
},

voteUpAttributes: function() {
  return {
    comment_id: this.model.get('id'),
    upvote: 1
  };
},

subtractUpVote: function ( event ) {

  var vote = new app.Vote(this.voteDownAttributes());
  vote.save({
    success: function (vote) {
      vote.toJSON();
    }
  });
},

voteDownAttributes: function() {
  return {
    comment_id: this.model.get('id'),
    downvote: -1
  };
}

});
```

If you notice in my addUpVote function I create a new Vote Model (app.Vote creates a new Model).  Whenever a change happens (a new model of Vote is created or changed) I would like to re-render the Comment View.

How would I go about setting a listenTo in my initialize function to look for the event on app.Vote model?  I thought something like

```
this.listenTo(app.Vote, 'add', this.render);
//instead of this.model 'app.Vote' because this.model is referring to the comment model.
```

Is my approach on this correct? If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: I think it would be `this.listenTo(this.model, 'all', this.render)` but you'd have to put this inside the `initialize` method of the `app.Vote` model

Comment: Unfortunately .listenTo cannot be used in a model, neither can .render(view).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Try this: In the `addUpVote` method, instead of having a private variable, have `this.addUpVoteModelInstance = new app.Vote(this.voteUpAttributes())` and then `this.listenTo(this.addUpVoteModelInstance, 'add', this.render)` in the initialize

Comment: I tried implementing those adjustments and I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenId' of undefined " in my console.  I wonder if I could just make another field within the model I can refer to as "this" and update that with the addUpVote field to trigger to be able to trigger the render function?

Comment: That could be because it doesn't have anything stored in `this.addUpVoteModelInstance` when the render function is called the first time. Try this: `return vote` in your `addUpVote` and `this.listenTo(this.addUpVote(), 'add', this.render)`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you are listening to the add event on a model so your approach doesn’t seem to be correct.

The “add” event is triggered when a model is added to a collection (models don’t have the add event, collections do).

From the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog): "add" (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.

So you could have a collection for your votes and listen for the add event on that collection, which would be triggered when you added a vote model to the vote collection.

So instead of listening to the "add" event which models do not have, you could listen to the "sync" event that would be triggered when your model was successfully synced with the server. But that still would not work because you are listening to the event on the model definition (app.Vote) and not on an instance created with that definition. The instance in your code would be the var **vote** = new app.Vote(this.voteDownAttributes());. So if you create a collection for your votes you need to listen to the "add" event on an instance of that collection and not on the collection definition.

Another approach would be to call this.render() in the success callback of the save method on your addUpVote and subtractUpVote methods (it is not the best approach but it would probably work for now). In your code that could look something like this:

```
addUpVote: function( event ) {
  var self = this;
  var vote = new app.Vote(this.voteUpAttributes());
  vote.save({
    success: function (vote) {
      vote.toJSON();
      self.render();
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Was this answer ok for you @HelloWorld?